# "In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above". My CompileSdkVersion = 33

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, compilation, sdk

I'm compiling my Ionic app on Android. I'm encountering this error when compiling the app.
The Java version being used is 19.0.2 and the Gradle version is 7.4.2.
I've checked all compileSdkVersions, and they are all set to 33, the targetSdkVersion is 33, and the minSdkVersion is 28.

Console error:
In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

I would really appreciate your help, as I can't find the solution on the net either. And I have tried all the solutions I have found on the net.
Thanks

Comment: Umm ... why Java 19?   That is end-of-life!!  Better to use Java 17 LTS or Java 21 LTS.

Comment: You use Ionic? RIP. Good luck. Tip: Do not edit the generated apk directly.